# Import SapSQLContext fails [ val vc = new SapSQLContext(sc) ]

Tags: vora

I have installed latest version of VORA and extensions on HortonWorks hadoop. I am encountering error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError while trying to import SAP SQL context.

Output from console attached below:

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.SapSQLContext

import org.apache.spark.sql.SapSQLContext

scala> val vc = new SapSQLContext(sc)

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.SimpleFunctionRegistry.<init>(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/CatalystConf;)V
        at org.apache.spark.sql.extension.ExtendableSQLContext.functionRegistry$lzycompute(ExtendableSQLContext.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.extension.ExtendableSQLContext.functionRegistry(ExtendableSQLContext.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.extension.ExtendableSQLContext.functionRegistry(ExtendableSQLContext.scala:18)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.UDFRegistration.<init>(UDFRegistration.scala:40)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.<init>(SQLContext.scala:296)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.extension.ExtendableSQLContext.<init>(ExtendableSQLContext.scala:18)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SapSQLContext.<init>(SapSQLContext.scala:18)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:22)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:27)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:29)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:31)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:33)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:35)
        at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:37)
        at $iwC.<init>(<console>:39)
        at <init>(<console>:41)
        at .<init>(<console>:45)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1340)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:674)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Installed Stack:

```
Service             Version 

HDFS                2.7.1.2.3

MapReduce2          2.7.1.2.3   

YARN                2.7.1.2.3   

Tez                 0.7.0.2.3   

Hive                1.2.1.2.3   

HBase               1.1.1.2.3   

Pig                 0.15.0.2.3  

Sqoop               1.4.6.2.3   

Oozie               4.2.0.2.3   

ZooKeeper           3.4.6.2.3   

Falcon              0.6.1.2.3

Storm               0.10.0  

Flume               1.5.2.2.3

Ambari Metrics      0.1.0   

Kafka              0.8.2.2.3    

Mahout              0.9.0.2.3   

Spark               1.5.2   

SAP HANA Vora       1.1.25.37
```

Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

TIA
Gopal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version list shows that you are running Spark 1.5.2 and Vora 1.1 Patch 1 (Ambari shows 1.1.25.37).

The error indicates that you are still using an earlier version of the Vora datasources. Could you please verify if you are using the Vora 1.1 Patch 1 datasources (spark-sap-datasources-1.2.10-assembly.jar)?

Please be aware:
Vora 1.1 Patch 1 works fully with Apache Spark 1.5.2. However, the Spark1.5.2 version coming with HDP2.3.4 is different from the Apache Spark1.5.2 version. There are 2 known issues with the HDP-Spark1.5.2 version: (1) when using Vora Thriftserver and (2) when using the Vora interpreter for Zeppelin. If you want to use any of those 2 I would recommend to use Apache Spark 1.5.2 installed outside of Ambari. 
With Vora1.2 both issues will be addressed and the HDP-Spark1.5.2 can be used.

Comment: Hello Frank, Thanks for the reply. The problem was there are two spark-sap-datasource<ver>.jar files in ~/vora/lib directory and the configuration file for the spark spark-defaults.conf, I have *velocity* entries. After moving out the older version of spark-sap-datasources*.jar file and correcting the config file by replacing 'velocity' with 'vora' the problem got fixed.